# Wordpress Site-Title

Tags: wordpress, blogs, title

I have a Problem with a Wordpress-Site. I have tryed and searched but i d'ont can find a Solution or serious Answer - nor Advise for my problem.

I like to change the Wordpress Site-Title. (I have a local Site to try this out...)
I have crashed the site 2 times.
The Title is now something like: "nicesite". i like to have "nice site"

I use the html on pages Plug-In, with Post-Name Permalink Structure.

I ask because i dont like to beginn from start again if i make mistakes again.

Why is Wordpress so much sensible in this things, i know it writes all in a database, but this is realy a big minus for the Wordpress-System.'

thanks very much if someone can explain me how to do, on local and live-Site's.

Comment: If you have a problem with a piece of code, please post it here. If, however, you have a problem with the administration of a WordPress blog, you should refer to the http://wordpress.org/support/ forums.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Go wordpress Dashboard-> settings -> General . Now enter site title

[image]

Comment: Sorry man, what are you tell me? read the question, i have tryed this and my site is crased. I go on with the advise i have allready become from this forum. please do not give me this weak advise anymore. tnx